# DD4T 2.0 with MVC 3

Tags: dd4t, 2013-sp1

I want to configure DD4T 2.0 alongside Tridion 2013 SP1, wondering if it could be configured with MVC 3  and VS 2010 as I am not able to find any document reference to this.
Please help with any guide to it.

Comment: 1 question to this: why? Those tools are nearly 6 years old.

Comment: The requirement is that sort of.

Answer (score 2):

These are very old versions and no longer supported by MS as also mentioned  by Rob in comments. so not recommended. But as your asked my observations are as follow.

I checked DD4T 2.0.0 beta source code (which i have on my machine). Up-to this version `System.Web.Mvc 3.0` is used and target .net framework 4.0 , then i think it matches your requirements.

but DD4T version `2.0.7` or later requires [MVC4](https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.MVC/blob/develop/source/DD4T.MVC4/packages.config) or MVC 5.

My personal view, you can do some homework, [download](https://github.com/dd4t) open-source code and target using your required framework and resolve any error (i don't expect much errors/warnings as up-to major version 2.0 is using mvc 3.0 and .net 4)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using DD4T < 2.0.7

Comment: @RobStevenson-Leggett i agree , but isn't it a minor version so the updates.

Comment: Pre 2.0.7 is considered "Beta" IIRC